# The database for Rumbl.Repo couldn't be created: killed

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I created a new project using `mix phx.new rumbl` which worked fine.
Then I went to the project folder using `cd rumbl`. After that I tried to run `mix ecto.create` which resulted in this error message:

```
D:\Elixir\Projects\rumbl>mix ecto.create

10:35:16.370 [error] GenServer #PID<0.212.0> terminating
** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) tcp connect (localhost:5432): connection refused - :econnrefused
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection/connection.ex:84: DBConnection.Connection.connect/2
    (connection) lib/connection.ex:622: Connection.enter_connect/5
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:249: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Last message: nil
State: Postgrex.Protocol
** (Mix) The database for Rumbl.Repo couldn't be created: killed
```

Yesterday mix ecto.create worked, but now it gives this error.
I have installed the dependencies without any problems
Elixir version: 1.8.2
phoenix version: 1.4.6

I have tried reopening the command prompt, restarting my laptop and using a different folder

Comment: The error says that the connection is being refused for localhost at port 5432. Is your database running? Check `psql`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your Postgres database is not running or not open on this port.

You should install postgres and start it.

If you don't want to handle with postgres issues or are not familiar with that, take a look on [this post](https://hackernoon.com/dont-install-postgres-docker-pull-postgres-bee20e200198) about how to have it running on a docker container.